# Filter nested array of objects to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects which is nested. How do I make an array of objects with this one getting values from nested properties as well? If onClick property is empty, it means there is a property called children and the parent element should not be a part of the new list. I need to loop through the children array and get the values. Please see the expected output below.

```js
const headers = [{
    title: 'Arun',
    id: 'arunId',
    onClick: 'onClickArun'
  },
  {
    title: "George",
    id: 'georgeId',
    onClick: '',
    children: [{
        title: 'David',
        id: 'davidId',
        onClick: 'onClickDavid'
      },
      {
        title: 'Patrick',
        id: 'patrickId',
        onClick: 'onClickPatrick'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Mark',
    id: 'markId',
    onClick: 'onClickMark'
  }
];

console.log(headers.map(item => {
  return {
    title: item.title,
    onClick: item.onClick
  }
}))
```

Expected Output:

```
[{
    title: 'Arun',
    onClick: 'onClickArun'
  },
  {
    title: 'David',
    onClick: 'onClickDavid'
  },
  {
    title: 'Patrick',
    onClick: 'onClickPatrick'
  },
  {
    title: 'Mark',
    onClick: 'onClickMark'
  }
]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with a recursive callback.

```js
const
    map = ({ title, onClick, children }) => onClick
        ? { title, onClick }
        : children.map(map);

var headers = [{ title: 'Arun', id: 'arunId', onClick: 'onClickArun' }, { title: "George", id: 'georgeId', onClick: '', children: [{ title: 'David', id: 'davidId', onClick: 'onClickDavid' }, { title: 'Patrick', id: 'patrickId', onClick: 'onClickPatrick' }] }, { title: 'Mark', id: 'markId', onClick: 'onClickMark' }],        
    result = headers.flatMap(map);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `Array.prototype.reduce`, where you just need to check if the parent `onClick` prop is empty and the `children` prop is present or not:

```js
var headers = [{ title: 'Arun', id: 'arunId', onClick: 'onClickArun' }, { title: "George", id: 'georgeId', onClick: '', children: [{ title: 'David', id: 'davidId', onClick: 'onClickDavid' }, { title: 'Patrick', id: 'patrickId', onClick: 'onClickPatrick' }] }, { title: 'Mark', id: 'markId', onClick: 'onClickMark' }];


function getObject(headers, acc){
  return headers.reduce((acc, ele) => {
   if(!ele.onClick.length && ele.children){
      acc = getObject(ele.children, acc);
   }else{
      acc.push({"title": ele.title, "onClick": ele.onClick});
   }
   return acc;
  }, acc);
}
console.log(getObject(headers, []));
```

Comment: Good answer, but your solution does not take into account nested children.

Comment: @YuriKhomyakov yeah sorry, If forgot to add the recursive step which is needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need a depth first search.
You run on the array, for each item with children recurse on it and pass along the existing array. otherwise, add the item to the list.

```
function getChildren(array, total = []){
  for(let item of array) {
    if(item.children) {
      getChildren(item.children, total)
    } else {
      total.push({
        title: item.title,
        onClick: item.onClick
      })
    }
  }
  return total
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let headers = [{
  title: 'Arun',
  id: 'arunId',
  onClick: 'onClickArun'
},
{
  title: "George",
  id: 'georgeId',
  onClick: '',
  children: [{
    title: 'David',
    id: 'davidId',
    onClick: 'onClickDavid'
  },
  {
    title: 'Patrick',
    id: 'patrickId',
    onClick: 'onClickPatrick'
  }
  ]
},
{
  title: 'Mark',
  id: 'markId',
  onClick: 'onClickMark'
}
]
// take children, only if onClick is empty
.map(item => item.onClick ? item : item.children)
// make flat array
headers = [].concat.apply([], headers)
    .map(item => { 
        const temp = {};
        temp.title = item.title;
        temp.onClick = item.onClick;
        return temp; // take only onClick and title property from each item
})
```